# Unanswered view filtered on a tag without questions lists all questions

Tags: bug, unanswered-questions

When switching to the unanswered tab, for a particular tag which has no questions, it shows all questions instead of none.

Typical use case, watching the [unanswered questions for my tags](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=mytags), and clicking on one of these tags to filter the view.

Example: https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/waffles-and-unicorns

Comment: Can you clarify how you got to that page? Starting at http://stackoverflow.com/tags/waffles-and-unicorns, switching to the "unanswered" tab links to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/waffles-and-unicorns?sort=unanswered&pagesize=50 which shows no questions as expected.

Comment: @hammar - the opposite way. Like I said, you start from "my tags" on the unanswered view.